# why the time is different from my TIME_ZONE in settings.py

Tags: django, sqlite, datetime, timezone

I'm using Sqlite for my project database.
I need date and time in my model so i'm using this field.

```
date = models.DateTimeField()
```

On the result template(results.html), the time is correct (localtime or  TIME_ZONE in my settings.py)
The problem is, when i check the database on Django admin page and sqlite db file, it seems like my timezone setting is not applied.(so, maybe UTC)

What is the problem and how could i fix this?

I think the template's parameters are from view, so the timezone.now() is correct and passes the right time.
So my guess is that 'date=timezone.now()' passes to sqlite like this:

```
insert into table values (date=datetime('now'))'
```

and the timezone of sqlite is maybe set to UTC default.

This is what i'm guessing. Am i right? Also i do not know how to set sqlite database timezone...

p.s On the other side, I also think when we set settings.py TIME_ZONE, django would manage all these things.
So don't know where to approach. Spending almost 2 days on this problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In settings.py, set

```
USE_TZ = False
```

can fix this problem

Comment: wow.. problem solved. Thanks a lot.
Could you explain why it does work or why it had not been worked? 
because I've never seen someone saying that set USE_TZ=False.

Comment: If you set USE_TZ=True, django will save your datetime as UTC in database, and when you render something in template,django transform the UTC to your TIME_ZONE in your settings.py.You can read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/) for more detail.